# Check multiple organizational units (ou) with django_auth_ldap

Tags: django, ldap, django-authentication

Our ldap is set up so that we have multiple different organizational units (ou). I currently have a django project using django_auth_ldap to connect to our ldap server so people can login with their ldap credentials. However I can only get it to work for one ou when I need it to work with multiple ones. I currently have it set up as thus

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.net"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=people_1,dc=example,dc=net",
   ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {"first_name": "givenName",
                           "last_name": "sn",
                           "email": "email",
                           }
```

This works to get people from the people_1 group. How can I set it up so that it will also select from another container such as people_2? I have tried just adding "ou=people_1,ou=people_2" which doesn't seem to work. I am still fairly new to understanding ldap so I apologize if this may be in fact something trivial to fix and just haven't been searching properly to find the answer. Took me awhile to just get django_auth_ldap just to work for me (extremely happy when I did!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the base object to `dc=example,dc=net`: then the search scope of `subtree` you have specified will search all subtrees under `dc=example,dc=net`. For more information about the LDAP search request and response operations, see my blog entry ["Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/). Even though the examples use command-line tools, the concepts will assist you.

Also, as a good programming practice, you should supply a [size limit](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/#size-limit) and a [time limit](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/#time-limit). The defaults for these parameters differ based on your API and may not suit your needs.

Comment: Ah ha! Figured it was something simple like that. I was thinking for some reason that an ou needed to be specified before it went searching. That makes sense now. Thank you!